# Date stored in table is wrong in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Can you tell my the date in the SQLite database is taking  as 
12/3/1899 instead of 12/3/2009.
I am inserting correct date while saving in this format. I can't understand what is the reason.What conversion has to be done in Insert Statement. Can any one help me out.

```
CREATE TABLE [PIs] ( [PIGUID] GUID PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
[CompanyGUID] GUID NOT NULL,
[No] varCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
[Dt] TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
[SupplierLgrGUID] GUID NOT NULL,
[SupplierLgrAddressGUID] GUID NOT NULL,
[SupplierBillNo] varCHAR(50) NULL,
[SupplierBillDt] TIMESTAMP NULL,
[CrDays] INTEGER NULL,
[DueDt] TIMESTAMP NULL,
[Narration] varCHAR(300) NULL,
[CreatedDt] TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
[LastEditedDt] TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
)
```

My Insert Statement is as follow:

```
INSERT INTO PIs(
  PIGUID,CompanyGUID,No,Dt,SupplierLgrGUID,SupplierLgrAddressGUID,
  SupplierBillNo,SupplierBillDt,CrDays,DueDt,Narration,CreatedDt,
  LastEditedDt)
VALUES(
  '806aeec2-762a-432e-800f-0354df3b7852' ,
  '375888f5-e1a5-4c75-9154-62ffc83dca97', 'PI/0809/004' ,
  datetime('8/19/2009 12:44:25 PM'),
  'ff376218-c2d9-4e02-86e6-e90c8d5efc43',
  '7dad4725-2e37-4596-88f4-7b088f0d91c4', '0021',
  datetime('8/19/2009 12:44:25 PM'), 12,
  datetime('8/31/2009 12:44:25 PM'), 'narration',
  datetime('now'),datetime('now')
)
```

I have installed SQLite 3.3.8 and my operating system is Windows Vista.

Any help would be appreciated..

Regards

Asif

Comment: Please post the acutal code you're using, that will make it much easier for people to help you.

Comment: Please check the code below: I have converted into datetime('') but gives me strange error : SQL logic error or missing database

Comment: Please don't put additional information into an answer; rather, click "edit" below the question to append the information there. I have incorporated the text from your answer into your question; now please delete your "answer".

Comment: please refer to my problems once if can you suggest me some solutions.

Answer (score 5):

The sqlite format for date is the ISO standard ie YYYY-MM-DD and not the one you have used
See [Sqllite date format](http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Try 
    SELECT date('now');
to see

Answer (score 2):

This [link](http://libdbi-drivers.sourceforge.net/docs/dbd_sqlite3/x123.html) has some information you should read on using TIMESTAMP and DATETIME for SQLite.

Here's an excerpt:

> TIMESTAMP, DATETIME
>   A string type of unlimited length used to store date/time combinations. The required format is 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS', anything not following this pattern is ignored.

Comment: That link is specific to a particular libdbi driver, *not* to SQLite in general.  SQLite does not enforce any particular format for DATETIME fields (DATETIME is not an internally recognised format; internally it only distinguishes between null/integer/floating point/text/binary blob).  Having said that, as indicated by Mark's answer, the date/time functions that SQLite provides do expect dates to be specified in one of a limited set of formats (one of which happens to be the format you recommended).

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with this one also...  If your using VB.NET here is how to insert the TimeStamp, I mean DateTime into SQLlite

DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o")

The important part is the .ToString("o") because this formats the date to ISO 8601

Here is the link that explains everything about the format - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip

It looks like this when it goes into the database.
2010-12-16T02:09:55.7870590Z

But After you insert the data it looks like this.

12/16/2010 2:09:55 AM

Hope this helps someone else out there.